# Where should I ask Google App Script and complex function questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been working on developing more powerful reporting Google Spreadsheets. I'm regularly looking for help with complex functions and occasionally with Google App Script. I find myself looking on both Stack Overflow and Web Apps for answers, but I'm not sure where I should be asking the questions.

- Where should I ask 'complex' function questions?
- Where should I ask Google App Script questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either looks to be appropriate, but with over 14,000 questions tagged [`google-apps-script`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) on Stack Overflow, that's probably where you're more likely to get an answer to a code-based question.

For non-code questions about Google Sheets, Web Apps is definitely the right place.