# Should we add Web Applications to "Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?"?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

Web Applications has an increasing number of questions about automating tasks in Google apps like Gmail, Docs, Slides but mostly in Sheets. This is done by using Google Apps Script which is a SaaS that allows to create *user defined functions*, *custom functions* (spreadsheet functions), *macros* and more.

By the other hand, and independently that there are very few questions about them,  according to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic bookmarklets (favlets) are on topic.

Is it OK to add Web Applications to [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691) (this is a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)) ?.

Related

- [Where should I ask Google App Script and complex function questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286736/289691)

Comment: The scope now says bookmarklets are off-topic.

Comment: @AndréLevy Thank you. I updated this weekend "Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? " but I had forgotten this thread. I updated the answer.

Comment: Aha! I see… So you vote to close my question saying it's off-topic there, doesn't suggest an alternate SE, instead suggests I ask around here, and it turns out you're the one providing the answers! Kafka would be *proud*.

Comment: Have you already asked here? AFAIK I didn't answered were to nowadays ask questions about bookmarklets.... yet :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

Be bold!

<sup>*Yes, I´m saying this to myself :)*</sup>

## Draft

### [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com)

**Web Applications** is a question and answer site for **power users** of web applications. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about ***using*** web applications including:

- <s>bookmarklets,</s> macros and scripts to automate some tasks
- user styles to change the way a web application page looks

All of the above should be to be applied on **a specific** web application of your choice.

NOTE: Questions about web application design/deployment/hosting are offtopic.

Comment: Update: I added the below draft to the related thread few days ago and it "survived", *until now* :)

Comment: Nowadays bookmarklets are off-topic on [webapps.se].